# Rails app - Search action showing all results instead of specific results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, model-view-controller, parameters

I want to search posts in my rails app. The problem is that when I search something, it shows me all posts in the database rather than specific results. Here is the action in `posts_controller.rb` :

```
def search
   @posts=Post.where('text LIKE ?', "%#{params[:text]}%")
end
```

This is the search form in the `index.html.erb`

```
<%=form_for(:post, :method=>'get', :url=>{:action=>'search', :html=> {:multipart=>true}}) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%=f.text_field(:text)%>
        <%=submit_tag("Search")%>
    </p>
  <%end%>
```

This is what the console shows me

```
Started GET "/posts/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&post%5Btext%5D=ror&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-18 17:48:07 +0500
Processing by PostsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "post"=>{"text"=>"ror"}, "commit"=>"Search"}
  Post Load (0.0ms)  SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (text LIKE '%%')
```

Can anyone fix this? Thanks in advance.

P.S I am running on Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `params[:text]` should be `params[:post][:text]`

```
def search
   @posts=Post.where('text LIKE ?', "%#{params[:post][:text]}%")
end
```